# Implementation of CountSort

Tags: c++, algorithm

So to cut a long story short, I am trying to implement countsort for vector. I have some error somewhere in my code, though I think that I have followed the pseudo code pretty strictly.

The function:

```
void csort(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b)
{
   vector<int> c(a.size());

   for(int i = 0; i <= c.size(); i++)
        c[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= a.size(); i++ )
    {
        c[a[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= c.size(); i++)
    {
        c[i]+= c[i-1];
    }
    for(int i = a.size(); i < 1; i--)
    {
        b[c[a[i]]] = a[i];
        c[a[i]] =c[a[i]] -1;
    }
}
```

The pesudo code:

```
let C[k] be a new array
 for i = 0 to k
 C[i] = 0
 for j = 1 to A:length
 C[A[j]]  = C[A[j]] +1
 for i = 1 to k
 C[i] = C[i]+  C[i-1] 
 for j = A:length downto 1
 B[C[A[j]]]  = A[j] 
C[A[j]]  = C[A[j]] -1
```

Comment: *" I have some error somewhere in my code"*. Compilation error? Logic error?

Comment: Logical error, the program crashes after a couple of seconds.

Comment: I recommend learning how to step through your code in a debugger.  That would have shown you the *specific line* that was in error.  Crashes will become much less mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = a.size(); i < 1; i--)
```

This code won't work at all.

```
for j = A:length downto 1
```

↑ 
To implement this pseudo code, you should do like this

```
for(int i(a.size()-1);i>=0;--i)
```

And for code like this( `c[a[i]]` )，you will get run-time error if `a[i]<0` or `a[i]>=c.size()`

Answer (score 3):

The code as it is is very unreadable and error prone. In any case, what I first saw is that in the snippet below you will access `c[-1]` at the first iteration, thus incurring in undefined behaviour.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= c.size(); i++)
{
    c[i] += c[i-1]; // Evaluation of c[i-1] is illegal for i == 0
}
```

Comment: Yep!  It doesn't match the pseudocode either